# Последовательный вызов fetch_array

Tags: php

Мучает такой вопрос, подзабыл

Насколько я помню, нельзя выполнить что-то вроде этого:

```
$query = $cnct->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='2'");
$array = $query->fetch_array();

while ($array2 = $query->fetch_array())
{
 ... 
}
```

Или можно ? Т.е. дважды на 1 запрос сделать fetch_array

Comment: Ответ: Нельзя...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А в каких-нибудь случаях можно ? Можно ли такое проворачивать на postgre ? Увидел там такое с постусловием и возник сразу вопрос

Comment: Просто зачем тут такое надо вообще? обычно таких задач нет. А в целом. вроде запросы с подготовленными выражениями такое позволяют, типа pdo.

Comment: @Steam.apk [Подготовленные выражения. Множественное выполнение](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#multi)

Comment: нельзя, а главное не нужно. Нужно научиться разделать получение данных и работу с ними. Сначала надо получить все данные запроса в массив. после этого с этим массивом можно делать что угодно, выводить сколько угодно раз

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы )